# Why does 'yield' not overwrite key value pairs in PHP?

Tags: php, generator, yield

I came across this strange behavior with Generators, which is not described in the PHP Manual.

I have two foreach loops - the first sets some default values, and the second overwrites them. But since some key:value pairs are missing, I couldn't use array_merge(), so I tried to use Generators for this purpose.

I discovered that the yield keys are overwritten in associative arrays even though [docs say](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php):

> The syntax for yielding a key/value pair is very similar to that used to define an associative array, as shown below.

Example:

```
function yieldTest()
{
    // those are array values (in my code - taken from data source; here static example)
    $arr1 = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3];
    $arr2 = ['b' => 'B', 'd' => 'D'];

    // 1st loop
    foreach ($arr1 as $k => $v) {
        yield $k => $v;
    }

    // 2nd loop
    foreach ($arr2 as $k => $v) {
        yield $k=>$v;
    }
}

foreach(yieldTest() as $k=>$v) {
    var_dump($k . ' = ' . $v) . "\n";
}
```

This results with

```
string(5) "a = 1"
string(5) "b = 2"
string(5) "c = 3"
string(5) "b = B"
string(5) "d = D"
```

So keys haven't been overwitten. I was expecting to get the following output:

```
string(5) "a = 1"
string(5) "b = B"
string(5) "c = 3"
string(5) "d = D"
```

Is this correct behavior?

Comment: You're seeing the behaviour I would expect to see. I'm not understanding what you think the issue is with using `array_merge`?

Comment: what's the output from print_r(yieldTest()); ?

Comment: Which bit is strange behaviour? A Generator yields what you tell it to yield, whether you've yieded the same key before or not, whether the key is a Boolean, an integer, an object (you can even yield a resource as a key if you really want to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generator is not an associative array. It says *"[t]he **syntax** for yielding a key/value pair is very similar to [..] an associative array"*; it does not say at all that a generator *behaves* like an associative array.

In fact, it *can't* behave the same and deduplicate keys, since the keys aren't known all at once. Each key is generated *when required*, not before. The `foreach` syntax for looping over a generator is actually syntactic sugar for this:

```
function foo() {
    while (true) {
        yield mt_rand(1, 2) => 'foo';
    }
}

$foo = foo();
$foo->next();
echo $foo->key(), ' => ', $foo->current(), PHP_EOL;
$foo->next();
echo $foo->key(), ' => ', $foo->current(), PHP_EOL;
$foo->next();
echo $foo->key(), ' => ', $foo->current(), PHP_EOL;
$foo->next();
echo $foo->key(), ' => ', $foo->current(), PHP_EOL;
```

[This will yield the same key many times, unpredictably.](https://3v4l.org/275iF) It should be obvious that it does not behave like an array at all. It just yields a pair of values, but those are not part of an array at all and are hence not deduplicated. Further, the generator only yields the next value when asked to, otherwise the above would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful explanation.